# Sorting EntityFramework computed columns

Tags: c#, telerik, entity-framework-4, radgrid

How do I handle sorting in RadGrid (or any other Grid) using EntityDataSource on computed columns ( in EF partial classes eg.: `DisplayName { get { retrun this.Name + " " + this.LastName;}}`  ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Like this.](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/24/client-side-properties-and-any-remote-linq-provider)

Comment: Is this still relevant? The nuget package haven't been updated since 2011 and the article is from 2009.