# Custom property error in linq to entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using EF4 and I am getting an error with my custom property.  I have 2 properties in my Application class, namely **Initials** and **Surname**.  It is a partial class.  I created a custom property in my Application class called **Owner**, and it looks like this:

```
public partial class Application
{
   public string Owner
   {
      get
      {
         return Initials + " " + Surname;
      }
   }
}
```

When I add it to my grid like this:

```
m => m.Owner
```

Then I get the following error:

**The specified type member 'Owner' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.**

How do I fix this?

Thanks
Brendan

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting EntityFramework computed columns ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3165187/sorting-entityframework-computed-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should show more code because at the moment description of your problem is not complete. Anyway you can't use Owner property in any Linq query working with IQueryable (Linq to entities). Custom properties can never appear in Linq to entities query because such query is mapped to SQL where the property doesn't exist. You first have to select data with Linq to entities, call ToList or AsEnumerable and than select properties including Owner in Linq to objects.

Comment: There must be some way to "translate" custom property for LINQ to Entities. It should allow you doing something like this:


context.Entities.Select(e => e.CustomProperty).ToTranslatedList().

Comment: @GiorgiZautashvili: No. There isn't any translation available and I doubt it is even possible to do something like that in generic way because the .NET code in custom property would have to be translated to SQL by some automagic.

Comment: Ladislav! I'm glad you answered, thought this is a very old post :)
Actually I found something interesting. Take a look please:

http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/24/client-side-properties-and-any-remote-linq-provider

this is what I was looking for.


P.S. I remember your answers since I started experimenting with EF. Many of your suggestions helped me make my first steps right. Thank you for this :) (a bit of sentiment here :)))

Comment: @GiorgiZautashvili: That's quite nice solution. It uses explicit solution to provide expressions for EF which is probably the only way to do that and it is definitely more complex than just write FirstName + Surname.

Comment: Yep, it's quite complex, but you have to write it once. It looks like mapping tools (e.g. AutoMapper), which look ugly, but saves coding a lot.